# Обработчик событий не работает в вызываемой функции php

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование, form, redbeanphp

Мне нужно вызвать функцию setButtons и в ней проверять нажатие нужных кнопок, но код в isset выполняется сам по себе. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить и что нужно сделать для корректной работы? Я новенький в php, не кидайтесь палками пожалуйста, для меня это важно
Если пишу  print $_POST - пишет : Array()
Не понимаю

```
<?php
require "php/include_db.php";  
$src = null;

$locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', 1);
$src = $locationInfo->location_image;
echo $src;
setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);

function setButton($locationInfo_travel){
            $arr_travels = explode(' ', $locationInfo_travel);
            for($i=0; $i<count($arr_travels); $i++){
            echo ", ", $arr_travels[$i];
            }
if(isset ($_POST['location_button_1'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[0]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
            setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
}if(isset ($_POST['location_button_2'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[1]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
            setButton($locationInfo->location_travel);
}if(isset ($_POST['location_button_3'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[2]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
}if(isset ($_POST['location_button_4'])){
            $locationInfo = R::load('locationsdb', $arr_travels[3]);
            $src = $locationInfo->location_image;
            echo $src;
 }
}
?>
```

Форма:

```
<div class="location_buttons_container">
                <div class="buttons_container">
                <form method="post" action="Game.php">
                    <ul class="buttons_menu">
                        <li>Локации</li>
                        <li ><span ><button id="location_button_1" name="location_button_1" >Главные ворота</button></span><em>3 сек.</em></li>
                        <li><span><button name="location_button_2">Торговый квартал</button></span><em>2 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span><button name="location_button_3">Замок</button></span><em>5 сек</em></li>
                        <li><span><button name="location_button_4">Гильдия</button></span><em>4 сек</em></li>
                    </ul>
                        </form>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: вместо `print $_POST` напишите `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>'`

Comment: Array( [location_button_1 ] => )
Вывело это, но мне это ничего не дало

Comment: а это так и задумано, что `if`ы внутри функции?

Comment: Да. Я хочу вызывать функцию, внося определенные параметры, по нажатию кнопок внутри ее